# Wireless doesn't work on a Centrino Wireless N chip in a Sony Vaio VPC-EG16FM/B

Tags: 11.04, wireless, intel-wireless

First off I'd like to say that I am sort of new to Linux in general.  I recently bought a new Sony Vaio laptop (model VPC-EG16FM/B) and I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on it but I am having problems enabling the wireless in Ubuntu and when I did a wired connection to look for a proprietary driver to enable the wireless Ubuntu could not find one.  I googled everywhere to see if I can find a solution but I couldn't find an answer for the Sony Vaio laptop that I have.  I talked to someone I knew that worked with Ubuntu/Linux about this issue and he couldn't find an answer for me so he recommended that I come here.  The guy I talked to wanted me to share the results I got for both the 'lspci' and 'ifconfig -a' commands here because it might help others figure out what might be wrong.

- Result for `lspci` command:

  ```
  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
  00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
  00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
  00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
  00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
  00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
  02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 (rev 67)
  03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5209 (rev 01)
  09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Device 1083 (rev c0)
  ```
- Result for `ifconfig -a` command:

  ```
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
   collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
   RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
   Interrupt:44

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
        RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:2016 (2.0 KB)  TX bytes:2016 (2.0 KB)

  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:25:c2:4d:da:84  
        BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
  ```

Any help would be appreciated because I use Ubuntu for school and for the time being I have to hold onto my old laptop until I can get the wireless on my Sony Vaio to work.

Comment: Nathan - please add to your question the output of `sudo lshw -class network` and `rfkill list`

Comment: Weird, because the 6150 should be working out of the box according to [this](http://intellinuxwireless.org/).

Answer (score 1):

According [to this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/168481) you need to blacklist the acer-wmi module, first edit the blacklist file with a text editor:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then add this line at the bottom:

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Then save the file and reboot.